# Insert into mysql tables

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to insert some records to 2 tables at same event

```
    private void Btngravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;database=saude;Password=");
        
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand objcmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into dispensacao (DESTINATARIO,COD_UNIDADE,COD_DEPARTAMENTO,DATA,SOLICITANTE,DEFERIDO_POR) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)", conn);
        objcmd.Parameters.Add("@DESTINATARIO", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = Cmbdestinatario.Text;
        
        objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD_UNIDADE", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Txtcodigounidade.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Txtcodigounidade.Text);
        objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD_DEPARTAMENTO", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Txtcodigodep.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Txtcodigodep.Text);
       
        DateTime fdate = DateTime.Parse(Txtdata.Text);           
        objcmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fdate;
        objcmd.Parameters.Add("@SOLICITANTE", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = Txtsolicitante.Text;
        objcmd.Parameters.Add("@DEFERIDO_POR", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = Txtdeferido.Text;
        objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        conn.Open();
        objcmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into produtos_disp(COD_DISPENSACAO,COD_PRODUTO,PRODUTO,QUANTIDADE) values (?,?,?,?)", conn);
        string selectid = "select ifnull (max(ID),1) from dispensacao";
        objcmd = new MySqlCommand(selectid, conn);
        MySqlDataReader reader = objcmd.ExecuteReader();
        
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            Txtcodigo.Text = reader.GetString("ID");
        }
        //Txtcodigo.DataBindings.Add("Text", dtid, "ID");
        objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD_DISPENSACAO", Txtcodigo.Text);
        objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD_PRODUTO", dtproddisp.Rows[0][0]);
        objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRODUTO", dtproddisp.Rows[0][1]);
        objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRODUTO", dtproddisp.Rows[0][2]);
```

Code from the comment

```
string selectQuery = "SELECT * from departamento"; 
connection.Open(); 
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection); 
MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable(); 
dt2.Load(reader); 
Cmbdestinatario.DisplayMember = "nome"; 
Cmbdestinatario.ValueMember = "CODIGO"; 
Cmbdestinatario.DataSource = dt2; 
Txtcodigodep.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt2, "CODIGO");
```

The first part is working, I can see records inserted on dispensacao table, but the second isn't working, error:

> Could not find specified column in results: ID

and I need to get products from datagridview,

App screen:
[image]

MySQL Dispensacao table:
[image]

My problem now is inserting those selected products from datagridview on database and get the id from dispensacao to insert on products table,

Comment: is there a good cause why you run `MySqlDataReader reader = objcmd.ExecuteReader();`before assigning values to it. And i have the feeling i saw this already yeaah the same problem as your last question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68245180/mysql-c-sharp-search-textbox

Comment: Do you set the ID as an autonumber column? If yes then you could get the value assigned to that column using _objcmd.LastInsertedID_

Comment: yes, can i use it to get the last id from the table

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616003/data-binding-for-textbox  but i only assijm the value to the textbix and skip the databinding part

Comment: there are no explanation on that link

Comment: technically ... you could use Txtcodigo.Text = reader.GetString(0); ... but the way you are attempting to get the ID on the insert is a concern

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert more rows in a database(from what I known), you should add a checkbox in a DataGridView Column and store checked rows to a list. Then you should use a for loop to insert each data to Database by list values.
If you want the code please comment me.